# How to get the secondary private IP address of an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm assigning automatically a **secondary private IPv4 address** during launch of my instances. To configure Ubuntu to recognize this secondary IP I need to run

```
ip addr add 10.0.1.15/24 dev eth0
```

To access the primary private IP address I have found this command (described in the [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#ip-addressing-eips) and in [figaros question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525702/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-an-amazon-ec2-instance-on-reboot)):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

But how can I get the secondary IP address to run the ip command automatically on startup? For Amazon Linux Systems there's the ec2-net-utils package wich can handle this automatically.

Comment: I typed "ubuntu run command on startup" into Google and found many results. I'd have told you what they were, but it depends on whether you're using systemd or something else. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd) will probably solve it for you.

Comment: Thank you Tim, but I have no problem to run my scripts on startup and I know how to do that.  I need a way to get the secondary private IP address of my Amazon EC2 instance, so I can use it within my scripts. There`s a solution for the primary IP address in the AWS Docs but not for the secondary IP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get secondary address with 2 commands.

Get mac address of your network interface

```
MAC=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac`
```

Get all IP addresses for this mac address

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/${MAC}/local-ipv4s
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of [antrost answer](https://serverfault.com/a/883439/342059) (his curl request returns all ip addresses) I was able to write the following bash script wich returns the **secondary** private IP only and configures Ubuntu to recognize it:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAC=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac`
ADDRESSES=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/${MAC}/local-ipv4s`
arr=($ADDRESSES)
if [ ${#arr[@]} -ge 2 ];
then
  ip addr add ${arr[1]}/24 dev eth0
fi
```